# Buffer Overflow check instruction on x86

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86

The following were the *first* 3 instructions that were generated for a function I was disassembling. (Visual C++ 2015 on Windows 7, 32-bit application.)

```
push    218h
mov     eax,offset MyModule!_log_pentium4+0x8cbf (53c0b577)
call    MyModule!_EH_prolog3_GS (53ad7977)
```

I don't understand the 2nd instruction. My actual function (in source form) has only 5 lines and no where in there I am using any math functions (which is what a Google search for `_log_pentium4` gets related to.) Its also quite possible that value in eax is used in the subsequent call to the Buffer Overflow security check routine. I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: The `+0x8cbf` offset just tells you that the disassembler had no idea what is being passed.  Certainly nothing to do with "log_pentium".  We don't know either.  Looks like this function call sets up an exception handler, it would use an internal table that does not otherwise appear in your code.

Comment: To expand on Hans's comment and explain where `log_pentium4` comes from, see [this blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131115-00/?p=2653). Basically, it's the last symbol that the debugger has at that approximate location, so it uses it and adds the necessary offset.

Comment: @CodyGray Raymond's blog post did it for me. Thanks! I got sidetracked by that _log_pentium name. Thank you too Hans.

Comment: @HansPassant Also, how did you figure out that the function is setting up an exception handler based on that one instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyModule!_log_pentium4+0x8cbf (53c0b577)` - this is pointer to so called  scope table (array of `EH*_SCOPETABLE_RECORD`).

read more about this for example here - [Where is my exception handler code in the function disassembly?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/satyem/2011/12/22/where-is-my-exception-handler-code-in-the-function-disassembly/) or here - [reversing Microsoft Visual C++ Part I: Exception Handling](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21)

also you can look in msvc crt folder - *\VC\crt\src\i386\chandler4.c* or like this (depended from crt version)

```
typedef struct _EH4_SCOPETABLE_RECORD
{
    ULONG                       EnclosingLevel;
    PEXCEPTION_FILTER           FilterFunc;
    union
    {
        PEXCEPTION_HANDLER      HandlerAddress;
        PTERMINATION_HANDLER    FinallyFunc;
    } u;
} EH4_SCOPETABLE_RECORD, *PEH4_SCOPETABLE_RECORD;
```

in second link this structure is named as `_SCOPETABLE_ENTRY`

Comment: and all this of course only for x86. x64 have absolute different exception handling (not in stack at all)

Comment: The blog posts were very informative and I now have a better understanding. I still have to ask you the same Q I asked Hans above. How did you figure out its a pointer to an exception handling scope table? I mean, what gave it away?

Comment: @ForeverLearning - this is standard function prolog with c++ exception handling (try/catch) . `218h` this is space will be reserved for local vars, and name [*_EH_prolog3_GS*](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21) is known. so known is arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently passing a parameter value to the function using the EAX register.